# jquery++ drop function

Tags: jquery

Hi im trying to make a darg and drop question.

I want top use this ++ code:
http://jsfiddle.net/donejs/3NkZM/light/

i want the box to turn green for correct and red for incorrect.

Ie i am drag would be correct
and drag me to to be incorrect

i have tried a few different methods such as:

```
    $('.drag').on('draginit', function(ev, drag) {
        // Create a ghost for this drag
        drag.ghost();
    });

    $('.drop').on({

        'dropover' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        },
        'dropout' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        },
        'dropon' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
            if('#correct') {
                $(this).addClass('green')   
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('red') 
            };
        };
});
```

can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML: (you have to say which one is correct)

```
<div class="drag correct">
    I am a drag
</div>

<div class="drag">
    Drag me, too
</div>

<div class="drop">
    Drop zone
</div>
```

JS: (you have to check if the dropped element is ".correct" and, if true, add a "correct" class to the dropzone)

```
$('.drag').on('draginit', function(ev, drag) {
    // Create a ghost for this drag
    drag.ghost();
});

$('.drop').on({
    'dropover' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    },
    'dropout' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    },
    'dropon' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
        $(this).html('Dropped: ' + drag.element.html());
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');

        $(this).addClass('dropped');
        if($(drag.element).is('.correct')) {
            $(this).addClass('correct');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('correct');
        }
    }
});
```

Add to CSS (color the dropzone):
    ​

```
.dropped {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropped.correct {
    background-color: green;
}
​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3NkZM/273/

Answer (score 2):

You can try JQuery Draggable also.
Just a sample to show, you can make as required.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintufrancis/n6tCQ/4/)

**Note:** Dragabbles will not work in Touch Screen devices unless u add **JQuery Touch Punch** plugin.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="right_ans" class="drag">
  I am a drag
</div>

<div id="wrong_ans" class="drag">
  Drag me, too
</div>
<div id="drop_target" class="drop">
  Drop zone
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
font-family: Helvetica,"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.drag {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.drop {
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#right_ans").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  cursor: "move",
  drag: function() {
    $("#right_ans").addClass('dragged');
  }
});

$("#wrong_ans").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  cursor: "move",
  drag: function() {
      $("#wrong_ans").addClass('dragged');
  }
});

$("#drop_target").droppable({
  accept: "#right_ans, #wrong_ans",
  drop: function() {
    if ($('#right_ans').hasClass('dragged')) {
        $(".drop").css('background-color', 'green');
        $('#right_ans').removeClass('dragged')
    }
    if ($('#wrong_ans').hasClass('dragged')) {
        $(".drop").css('background-color', 'red');
        $('#wrong_ans').removeClass('dragged')
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively test the content

```
var answers = {"I am a drag":"green","Drag me, too":"red"}

'dropon' : function(ev, drop, drag) {
    var answer = drag.element.html();
    $(this).html('Dropped: ' + answer);
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass(answers[$.trim(answer)]);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ztqs3/)